# How to plot an array in a histogram in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a histogram of an array. In x-axis  I want to plot the values and in y-axis I want to plot **the total number of elements** in the array. How should I plot it? here is my array.Thanks in advance. I know how to plot the values but I don't know how to plot the total number of elements in y-axis.

```
[-0.1286385  -0.8456761  -0.95667267  0.06595946  0.78725716 -0.96428178
 -0.87616352  0.35353555  0.04112559  0.34965274  0.56990385 -0.62902429
  0.26539379  0.18312748  0.70591512  0.69791719 -0.52411982 -0.79432468
  0.68757033  0.48375113 -0.64103554  0.21627639 -0.81852819  0.99536198
  0.94046895 -0.06609427 -0.00627846  0.20028275  0.36961461  0.90935696
 -0.76545115 -0.57905796  0.04596451  0.96142961 -0.11043977  0.00557756]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(your_array)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted - it's correct. You can additionally pass the number of bins as `plot.hist(arr, n)`